# Windows partition is unbootable after installing Ubuntu in dual-boot mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Earlier my system was dual booting Windows 10 and Fedora 28. Last week, I switched to Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

I used a Live-USB and installed Ubuntu, on the same 250 GB SSD as Windows,  after creating a partition for Linux, and without touching the Windows installation. Ubuntu is now the default OS but I can't boot into Windows using any method. Also Windows is not being displayed in the grub menu.

I have tried `update-grub` and Boot-Repair but nothing seems to work.

The Windows partition has all the data for the C: drive which I can check after mounting it in Linux.

I selected the GPT partition while using Rufus to create the bootable USB drive.  Is this the problem?

Is there a way to boot into Windows without losing the data, otherwise I'll have to format the complete system, reinstall Windows and then Ubuntu. I can reinstall Ubuntu if need be but I don't want to format the Windows partition.

[image: gparted]

[image: disks utility]

Comment: Did you try booting Windows from the EFI menu (some function key at power-up to allow selection of boot OS/device)?

Comment: Yes, the boot selector shows windows but it wont boot up.

Comment: With UEFI the boot and/or esp flags can only be on the ESP - system partition which is normally FAT32. Remove boot & esp flag from your Windows sda4 partition. How did sda2 get changed from normal FAT32 to FAT16. You may need to change that back, but need to back it up first and or may need a Windows repair disk to reinstall Windows UEFI boot loader and Boot-Repair to reinstall grub boot loader.

Comment: is there a way to change those flags in ubuntu os? will the repair option on bootable windows usb fix this thing?

Comment: You can use gparted in Ubuntu live installer, right click on partition. Not sure with Windows but boot flag usually was a set active command.